# Restricting access to storage account containing package blob for cloud service (extended support) deployment

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-storage-account

I'm nearly done migrating our cloud service (classic) deployments to cloud service (extended support). I'm working now on updating deployment pipelines. My package blob is located in a storage account. I create a SAS for the blob and use an [API call to management.azure.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/cloud-services/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP#apierror) to create/update the deployment, passing ARM template as the body of the request.

This works correctly as long as the storage account with the package blob has its network set to "allow access from all networks".  I want to restrict this access. I set the allow access from:

- specific IP addresses of our devops servers
- our own IP addresses
- private vnet/subnets for the cloud service

I also tick the "Allow Azure services on the trusted services list to access this storage account" checkbox.

Yet, API call fails with error message indicating access is not allowed to the blob.  When I change the storage account network configuration to "allow access from all networks", everything works correctly.

With lots of searches, I found only one hit explaining the same problem - https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/20299 - yet no solution has been suggested other than allowing access from all networks.

I must be missing some trick - but what is it? How can I restrict access to the storage account?

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve your issue, I believe you'll need to generate a SaS token and then append it to your packageUrl as a query parameter so

```
packageUrl + "?" + sasToken
```

In order to generate a sas token, you can use the azure CLI in your deployment process. I have used something like this:

```
# Generate the SaS token for use in the ARM Template
$tokenExpiry = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(15).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ");
$sas = az storage account generate-sas --account-name $account --expiry $tokenExpiry --https-only --permissions crlw --resource-types cso --services b
```

I found this link really useful:
[https://adamtheautomator.com/azure-sas-token/#:~:text=Generating%20a%20SAS%20Token%20using%20PowerShell,-To%20prevent%20having&text=PowerShell%20uses%20Azure's%20REST%20API,you'd%20like%20to%20access.](https://adamtheautomator.com/azure-sas-token/#:%7E:text=Generating%20a%20SAS%20Token%20using%20PowerShell,-To%20prevent%20having&text=PowerShell%20uses%20Azure%27s%20REST%20API,you%27d%20like%20to%20access.)

I hope this helps, I'm still struggling with trying to get a parameterised VMSize in my CSDEF during deployment but other than that I'm basically up and running.

Comment: I'm already using sas tokens. My doorbell can access the blob, but azure deployment fabric seems to require access to storage account from all networks.

Comment: Have you tried building your entire URL and just entering it into a browser window where you're not authenticated with Azure? 

I built up the URL like so:
(e.g.....)

`https://<storageName>.blob.core.windows.net/<containerName>?<sasToken>`

Then, if you can access it in a browser it may give you a better error, as once I had correctly built the SaS token it still wouldn't work, then I realised I wasn't requesting the proper permissions for that token.

I hope that helps, if not I'll continue to try to help you if you reply to this :)

Comment: Once I had got my SaS token into my ARM template as a parameter, I also noticed it was being added with unwanted quotation marks (") either side, so I also did a replace on that within the ARM template itself when I built that packageUri parameter so it looked like so
`"packageUrl": "[concat(variables('azureSettings').sasUri, '?', replace(parameters('sasToken'), '\"', ''))]",`

Comment: Then my "sasUri" parameter was built like this:

`"sasUri": "[concat('https://', parameters('azure_storageContainerName'), '.blob.core.windows.net', '/', parameters('azure_deploymentContainerName'), '/', parameters('buildVersion'), '/<packageName>.cspkg')]",`

Comment: I think you're missing the point.  The issue is not about authentication. It's about network access.  If I'm coming from a non-authorised network, even if I have correct authentication, Azure won't let me access any blob.  I'm talking about "Network" settings on the storage account.

Comment: OK, I understand, I was hoping that by building the correct URL, and running it in your browser, you would then be able to get a better error on determining your Network status.

If it helps, the container I have set up, is a private container. Just to clarify, are you using Storage Accounts V2, or classic Storage as you cannot use classic storage with Cloud Services (extended support)

It's just, if your SaS is correct and your URL for the blob is all correct, you should be able to access that regardless of your auth status

Comment: On a second look, it seems ours is enabled from all networks; so yeah I see your issue. I'm afraid I have not done it specifically on the Virtual Network for this storage account, however the container itself is private and you can only access those resouces with the correct SaS token anyway, so I'm not sure if your issue is something you should actually worry about if you can't publicly access the resources anyway